# Flutter Linux Build Encoding issue

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-build, flutter-linux

When building an linux app using flutter build linux.
It started to having an issue with displaying non-latin characters.

[flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ixz9.png)

This image provides some detail on the issue I'm encountering. All the squares are asian characters (Japanese, Chinese, Korean)
[Issue displaying non-latin characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThpJg.png)

Can someone please advise

tried different versions. Built to different environment(android, ios, web, and macos), no issue displaying characters, only on linux

Comment: Without a true [mcve] readers can only guess to solve your problem. While your's is not a bash question, read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info and search for the section "How to turn a bad script into a good question". Reducing the problem to simple steps may show you where the problem is on your own. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would want to reconfigure locales. I don't exactly know what flavour of Linux Flutter is, but there should be some way on installing/reconfiguring locales.

Once you have found out how, for the locale, you want to select en_US or en_UK (depending on which country you are in) with (Make Sure You Do This!) UTF_8. UTF_8 allows for your system to use international characters.

Afterwards, once locales has been configured, international characters should work!

I know that it works in Debian, so it should work similarly on your Linux system.

(You also might want to move/copy your question to SuperUser (superuser.com) because StackOverflow is for programming questions and SuperUser is for Linux and technical administrator questions)

Comment: The problem is I already tried to change the configuration of both Ubuntu and Raspberry Pi 4 devices to en_US and ko_KR. Still the same. Other application and browser is loading non-latin characters properly except for the flutter application I built. The weird thing is it all of sudden start happening with the same environment. Same env for building it(which I use docker)

Comment: The response appears to be more of a comment on the question rather than a proper answer.